# Prolog Cuts and query results

Tags: prolog

In a prolog program as stated below:

```
town(a).
town(b).
town(c).
town(d).
dam(e).
dam(f).
link(a,b).
link(a,c).
link(c,d).
link(b,d).
link(b,c).
link(c,e).
link(a,e).
link(d,f).
neighbour(X,Y):- link(X,Y) ; link(Y,X).
```

Are these the correct results from the following queries:

Query 1 - `?-dam(X), once(neighbour(X,Y)),town(Y).`

Results: `X=e Y=c; X=f Y=d`

Query 2 - `?-dam(X), neighbour(X,Y),!,town(Y).`

Results: `X=e Y=c`

Query 3 - `?-dam(X),!,neighbour(X,Y),town(Y).`

Results: `X=e Y=c; X=e Y=a`

Comment: I guess this is homework. You can try it yourself in any prolog system.

Comment: The system returns 'no' for all three, which I am almost certain is incorrect.

Comment: The results you are expecting are right. If it is returning 'no' to those queries I bet that you haven't consulted (loaded) your code.

Comment: Awesome thanks, let me see if I can consult my code.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are correct. You can keep in mind that once(Goal) is defined as Goal, !, i.e., your third query "dam(X),!,neighbour(X,Y),town(Y)." is equivalent to "once(dam(X)),neighbour(X),town(X)."